# Should I always use Core Data for my model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

The question is very simple.

- Should I use `Core Data` only to persist data, to store it locally on a `device` or should I use it ALWAYS just to manage my `application's model` even if I do not persist significant amount of `data`?

What do you think?

Comment: you either get __NO__ as your answer or primarily opinion-based answer.

Comment: well i don't mind getting few primarily opinion-based answers from knowledgable people

Comment: but it is not suitable for this site and it may get closed.

Comment: hmm, so how would you advice me to get an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data provides an infrastructure for change management and for saving objects to and retrieving them from storage. It is not, though, in and of itself a database. **You can use an in-memory store in your application.**

Use it Always ? : NO. Use it when you think that your require the features that the Core Data framework offers to you, like any other framework.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. As others said if you do not need persistent store just create runtime objects and manage them.

Even when you need persistent database, Core Data is not always the best solution. For example if you have multi-platform app, or if you plan to port your application in future I'll definitely consider use base sqlite3 with requests. This way I can use same database structure in my Android, iOS and BB application, and even my sql statements will be written only once(with their interface) and then I'll just need some platform specific implementation above them.